# Converting a C++ Checksum function to Java

Tags: java, c++, checksum

I'm trying to convert this C++ checksum to Java but for the time being I've failed. What am I doing wrong?

What is it supposed to do?
It is supposed to return a positive checksum for a buffer in OpenGL

Here's the C part.

```
DWORD QuickChecksum(DWORD *data, int size){

if(!data) {
    return 0x0; 
}

DWORD sum;
DWORD tmp;
sum = *data;

for(int i = 1; i < (size/4); i++)
{
    tmp = data[i];
    tmp = (DWORD)(sum >> 29) + tmp;
    tmp = (DWORD)(sum >> 17) + tmp;
    sum = (DWORD)(sum << 3)  ^ tmp;
}

return sum;
}
```

And here is what I have tried in Java. As far As I know DWORD is 32bit so I use int in a long to get a unsigned int which should be done in java with >>>?

I've been looking at this problem so much now that I've grown blind to it.

```
public static long getChecksum(byte[] data, int size) {
    long sum, tmp;
    sum = getInt(new byte[]{data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3]},true) & 0xFF;
    for(int I = 4; I < data.length; I += 4)
    {
        tmp = getInt(new byte[]{data[I],data[I+1],data[I+2],data[I+3]},true) & 0xFF;
        tmp = (sum >>> 29) + tmp;
        tmp = (sum >>> 17) + tmp;
        sum = (sum << 3) ^ tmp;
    }
    return sum & 0xFF;
}

private static int getInt(byte[] bytes, boolean big) {
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);
    return bb.getInt();
}
```

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Without looking at this in great detail, have you ensured that the endianness is correct?

Comment: What are the & 0xFF doing there?

Comment: Given that you ask the question "What is it supposed to do?", I suggest you take a step back and ask yourself whether you should be using it in the first place. The web is great for finding snippets of code but, personally, I like to understand what they're doing before I'm prepared to include them in my own work.

Comment: @PeteH It is not just a snippet that i've found from the internet, it's been in production code for a long time. ( given I didn't write the original one) But there is still a need for me to convert that particular piece of code to Java because of a change from C to Java in the development of the application. And that is why I know that the C part does give correct results in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious error is that, in three places, you AND the input word and the final checksum with `0xff`, losing the upper 24 bits. Presumably, you're trying to reduce the `long` value to 32 bits, which requires an AND with `0xffffffffL`. You'll also need to convert the return value of `getInt()` to `long` before doing that, otherwise you'll still get the sign extension you're trying to avoid.

My Java's a bit rusty, but I'm fairly sure that you'll get the correct results by sticking with `int`, as long as you use `>>>` for the right-shift (as you do).

You also have a bug where you unconditionally read the first four bytes without checking that the input isn't empty.

You'll also need to make sure that the input has a multiple of 4 bytes; either by checking the length, or by changing it to work with `int[]` rather than `byte[]` like the C version does. And of course there's no need for a `size` parameter, since Java arrays carry their size around with them.

The following should give the same results as the C version:

```
public static int checksum(int[] data)
{
    if (data.length == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    int sum = data[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < data.length; ++i) {
        int tmp = data[i];
        tmp = (sum >>> 29) + tmp;
        tmp = (sum >>> 17) + tmp;
        sum = (sum << 3)   ^ tmp;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Just made all of those changes, and even tried your code ( your code did give me results similar to right ones ), but the result is: OLD checksum = 4011644098 and new checksum is 713196854 and there is still negative checksums for some reason. Could it be that it has to be a long to work?

Comment: @user1897599: You'll get negative checksums in Java because Java has no concept of unsigned types. The binary value should be correct; if you really want a positive value, then I suppose you could mess around with `long` for the return value (`return (long)sum & 0xffffffffL;`) but it shouldn't be needed for the intermediate results. If you're getting different positive results, then either the data or the calculation is different. Try stepping through both with a debugger to see where the difference is.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, `>>>` performs unsigned shift, meaning it will insert bit value 0 to new bits shifted in, turning negative number to positive. Signed shift `>>` extends the sign bit, which is 1 for negative values, so negative numbers stay negative.

To fix your code, at least replace `0xFF` with `0xFFFFFFFF` in your & operations. Also, I think you may have to do that every time you assign to `tmp` and `sum`, not just once after the loop (not 100% sure, would have to go through the code to see if right bits get preserved and no extra bits sneak in even without ANDing, so better safe than sorry).

I'd also add as first thing in the method:

```
if (data.length & 3 != 0) 
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("byte buffer size not multiple of 4");
```

Also, I'd either remove the `size` argument, or actually use it instead of `data.length` (after checking it is valid), in case data might have more bytes than you want to process.

Answer (score 0):

The C++ version returns 32 bits of the `sum`, but your Java version does `& 0xFF`, which only leaves 8.

1. You do unsigned shift with `>>>` and all the other operations are defined so that their result in signed Java type is equal to the same operation on C++ unsigned type except for interpretation of the signed bit. So you can actually use `int` here.
2. If you keep using `long`, you need to use `& 0xFFFFFFFF` to get 32 bits.